# Bootstrap - Inside Tabpanel display block is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm working with Tabpanels, there are 4 tabs into Tabpanels and except first tab all tabs are "display none" by default.
Problem is when ever I click on second, third and fourth tab, content(Slider) inside which are display none their property is not changing to display block.

Please check with below code

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-12 pkg_rght_tabs_con">
  <div class="pkg_main_tabs">
    <ul class="mtabs visible-lg visible-md visible-sm">
      <li class="eactive"><a href="#mtab1">Features</a></li>
      <li><a href="#mtab2" id="aPrice">Journey</a></li>
      <li><a href="#mtab3">Gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#mtab4">Videos</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="mtab_container">
      
      <div id="mtab1" class="mtab_content" style="display: none;"> <span class="mtabs_seprate col-md-12 visible-xs"></span>
        <div class="row pop_costing_form">
          <div class="col-md-12"> <?php echo "$Date_Travel"; ?>
            </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div id="mtab2" class="mtab_content" style="display: block;"> <span class="mtabs_seprate col-md-12 visible-xs">Overview</span>
        <div class="valid_from_date"> <span class="vfd_arrow"></span> </div>
        <div class="row Validity_row" id="Valid01" style="display: block;
    width: 100%;">
          <input type="hidden" id="hdnvalidityVal" value="value">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div> <?php echo "$adesc"; ?>
              <div id="amazingslider-wrapper-1" style="display:block;position:relative;max-width:600px;margin:0px auto 86px;">
                <h2>Tour Photo Gallery</h2>
                <div id="amazingslider-1" style="display:block;position:relative;margin:0 auto;">
                  <?php  
                                include "connect.php";
                        
                                $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_gallery where aid=$aid and status='process'";
                                $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, $sql));  
                                ####### Fetch Results From Table ########
                                
                                $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                                {
                                $gimage=$row['gimages'];
                                
                                ?>
                  <ul class="amazingslider-slides" style="display:none;">
                    <?php echo "<li><img src='admin/gupload/$gimage' /></li>" ?>
                  </ul>
                  <ul class="amazingslider-thumbnails" style="display:none;">
                    <?php echo "<li><img src='admin/gupload/$gimage' /></li>" ?>
                  </ul>
                  <?php } ?>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div id="mtab3" class="mtab_content" style="display: none;"> <span class="mtabs_seprate col-md-12 visible-xs"></span>
        <div class="row pop_costing_form">
          <div class="col-md-12"> <?php echo "$Inclusions_Exclusions"; ?>
            </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="mtab4" class="mtab_content" style="display: none;"> <span class="mtabs_seprate col-md-12 visible-xs"></span>
        <div class="row pop_costing_form">
          <div class="col-md-12"> <?php echo "$how_to_book"; ?>
            </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="mtab5" class="mtab_content" style="display: none;"> <span class="mtabs_seprate col-md-12 visible-xs"></span>
        <div class="row pop_costing_form">
          <div class="col-md-12"> <?php echo "$tour_info"; ?>
            </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: and your question is ?

Comment: Means as you said? when you click on first, display first content, under first content, display second content when click on second? That type, you said?

Comment: tab are wrap with sliders and whenever i click on second or third tab, it is taking me inside individual tab but the issue is slider inside it which is having css property display block it is show display none

Comment: @HarshadPatil, can you please share images?

Comment: please check with below link, you will see tabpanel in that click on 2nd tab

http://reverdigital.com/demo-kalakrutti-1/page-details.php?id=13